# How to run 'join' command for multiple files (of 2 types) in a folder

Tags: bash

I have two types of files for a gene in a folder

File 1: FOS.tf.txt

```
ABL2
ACTN4
ADGRE5
ADIPOR2
ADRB2
ERCC4
EZR
FAS
FMO4
```

File 2: FOS.tt.txt

```
ABL2
CASP9
CCK
DDIT3
ERCC4
EZR
FAS
FMO4
```

After running command

```
join FOS.tf.txt FOS.tt.txt > FOS_final.txt
```

I got output file: FOS_final.txt

```
ABL2
ERCC4
EZR
FAS
FMO4
```

My question is that I have these two type of files (tf and tt) for 605 genes in a folder and I want to run join command together for all my genes and get 605 output files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your `.tf.txt` and `.tt.txt` files are in the same directory, the following command should work.

```
for tffile in $(ls *.tf.txt)
do
    prefix=$(basename $tffile .tf.txt)
    join ${prefix}.tf.txt ${prefix}.tt.txt > ${prefix}_final.txt
done
```

Comment: The `basename` call can be avoided by anchoring a regex with parameter expansion like so: `join ${tffile} ${tffile/%.tf.txt/.tt.txt} > ${tffile/%.tf.txt/_final.txt}`

Comment: @RamRS Cool! I guess it's up to the individual to decide which ugly solution is less ugly! :-)

Comment: Indeed. I wonder if `$()` is more performant than `${//}`.

Comment: @ Ram RS: 
I am getting this error
         ${tffile/%.tf.txt/_final.txt}: ambiguous redirect